# zipping files generated on the fly

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

how can you zip a bunch of files generated on the "fly"?

im testing with this small scale scenerio:

```
from time import strftime
import zipfile

# create new file
today = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

new_file = open('testing123.txt', 'w')
text = 'this file was just added:' + str(today)
new_file.write(text)

# create zip file and write to it
newZip = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
newZip.write('testing123.txt')
new_file.close()

print "file created"
```

two things, first the `testing123.txt` which is created at the top of the script is blank when you unzip the zip file created, and this should include a list of files that are generated in a loop.

so im wondering what the best approach to generate a bunch of files on the fly and then zip them all nicely to a zip folder.

Comment: you should first `new_file.close()` before starting to zip

Comment: you can have the zip open and keep appending

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason why the file appears empty after unzipping is that you did not *close* your text file after using it. Because you didn't close the file, your `write` was not actually committed to disk, so `ZipFile.write` saw an empty file. You can use `with` to automatically close the file when you're done with it, so you never have to forget `.close`:

```
with open('testing123.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write('this file was just added:' + str(today))
```

(You could also use `.flush()` to force the write to be committed, but that's less common).

Second, if you're generating file contents programmatically, then you should use `.writestr` to write a string without creating an actual file on disk:

```
newZip = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
newZip.writestr('testing123.txt', 'this file was just added:' + str(today))
newZip.close()
```